# How to use arm64 assembly to perform floating-point operation?

Tags: c++, assembly, arm64

How to use ARM64 assembly to perform floating-point operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication and division?

I tried

```
static double  __attribute__((naked, pure)) MyASMAdd(double sub1, double sub2) {
#ifndef __arm__
    asm("           ADD     x0, x0, x1");
    asm("           RET");
#endif
}
```

As above, if I use two **double** or **float** operations, the result will always be the first parameter
such as
3.2 + 4.6, which should be equal to 7.8, but the answer is 3.2.
In other cases, too.
But if I use **int** for both arguments, I can get the result I want。

```
static int  __attribute__((naked, pure)) MyASMAdd(int sub1, int sub2) {
#ifndef __arm__
    asm("           ADD     x0, x0, x1");
    asm("           RET");
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AArch64 calling convention](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ihi0055/d/procedure-call-standard-for-the-arm-64-bit-architecture) passes floats in s0-7 and doubles in the d0-7 registers.

Output from [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/AvUS4n):

```
add_d(double, double):
        fadd    d0, d0, d1
        ret
add_f(float, float):
        fadd    s0, s0, s1
        ret
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I can't find the answer in many forums with the keyword of [arm64 assembly floating-point arithmetic]. Thank you very much for your help. By the way, how can I start if I want to continue to learn the arm64 assembly developed by JNI based on Android?

Comment: "JNI" is an interface between Java and native code. Did you mean "where can I learn about ARM64 assembly?" Searching for "ARM64 assembly" or "AArch64 assembly" should already bring up some tutorials and references.

Comment: Well! Thank you! Thank you for your website https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @pnkj: The standard name for the 64-bit ARM architecture is AArch64, not ARM64.  Google that next time; Also ARM does have manuals.  e.g. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802a/a64_float_alpha.html and similar pages on keil's site with ISA reference guides.  But yeah if you don't know which instruction to use, ask a C compiler.